# Read multiple lines of floats from text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to save a gray scale image as a text image, each pixel is stored as a float `m_p_image` in my Image class.

from Image.h

```
/// Number of pixel along the horizontal axis
unsigned int m_width;


/// Number of pixel along the vertical axis
unsigned int m_height;


/// The pixel data
float* m_p_image;
```

from Image.cpp

```
//-------------
Image::Image():
//-------------
        m_width(0),
        m_height(0),
        m_p_image(0)
//------------------
{}
```

The image text files are set up like:

```
0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500
0.500   0.500   0.000   0.000   0.500   0.500   0.500
0.500   0.500   0.000   0.000   0.500   0.500   0.500
0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500
```

Though they can have any number of floats in them.

What is the best way for me to read these floats in and store them in my 1 dimensional float array `m_p_image`, and also get the number of floats on each row (`m_width`) and the number of floats on each column (`m_height`)? Is it best to read the lines as strings and then cast them?

Comment: text format is not quite suitable for images

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of it would be to specify the columns/rows in the top of the text and refrain from breaking the lines.

It will look something like this:

```
7 4
0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.000   0.000   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.000   0.000   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500   0.500
```

> Is it best to read the lines as strings and then cast them?

If you can assure that only float values are coming then directly reading them as float wouldn't be a bad idea (until requirement changes in the future).

Answer (score 0):

> store them in my 1 dimensional float array m_p_image

```
float m_p_image[width*height];
fstream fs("file.txt");
for(int i=0; i<width*height; i++)
  fs >> m_p_image[i];
```

But like other post says, if you want to store them in 1d array in your program, why bother store them as 2d in txt.

> get the number rows (m_width) and columns (m_height)

That would be easier if you don't mind store it as metadata in the very first line of file, say

```
2 3
0.1 0.1
0.1 0.1
0.1 0.1
```

Otherwise, you can always use `getline` function to read until `\n`, and then count the number of entities before newline.

```
string line;
std::getline(fs, line);
stringstream ss(line);
int m_width=0;
while(ss >> m_p_image[m_width++]) ;
```

m_height can be recorded by counting calls to getline.

Also, if you don't like istream, `fscanf` would be good too.